# jQuery - fadeIn speed not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an animation where the title fades out then some content fades in, I've got a little problem regarding the speed of the animation though.

No matter what I do I can't change the speed effect of the fadeIn method? The animation works perfectly apart from that. Can't seem to figure it out - any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.aboutQuery').click(function() {
    $('.mySec').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $('.aboutText').fadeIn(5000);
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.mySec {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: calc(95vh);
  width: calc(96vw - 1vh);
  transform: translate(calc((4vw + 1vh) / 2), 2.5vh);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.aboutText {
  padding-left: 5vw;
  padding-right: 5vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <ul id="headList">
    <li>
      <a class="aboutQuery" id="link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="link" href="#">CLASSES</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="mySec">
    <div class="info">
      <h1 class="title">Niki Gibbs Modern Pilates</h1>
      <p class="title2">Working From The Inside Out.</p>
      <img id="pilLogo" src="pilatesLog.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aboutSec">
    <div class="aboutInfo">
      <p class="aboutText">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show the problem in a JSFiddle?

Comment: @hansTheFranz why JSFiddle. The StackSnippets `<>` work well most of the time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't hiding the about text first. You need to add `display:none` to your CSS rules:

```
.aboutText {
  padding-left: 5vw;
  padding-right: 5vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  white-space: pre-line;
  display:none;
}
```

```js
$('.aboutQuery').click(function() {
    $('.mySec').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $('.aboutText').fadeIn(5000);
    })
  })
```

```css
.mySec {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: calc(95vh);
  width: calc(96vw - 1vh);
  transform: translate(calc((4vw + 1vh) / 2), 2.5vh);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.aboutText {
  padding-left: 5vw;
  padding-right: 5vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  white-space: pre-line;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <ul id="headList">
    <li>
      <a class="aboutQuery" id="link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="link" href="#">CLASSES</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="mySec">
    <div class="info">
      <h1 class="title">Niki Gibbs Modern Pilates</h1>
      <p class="title2">Working From The Inside Out.</p>
      <img id="pilLogo" src="pilatesLog.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aboutSec">
    <div class="aboutInfo">
      <p class="aboutText">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh yeah, was playing around with display none earlier aswell. Will mark as correct

Answer (score 0):

I think do you want to something like following:

Hide aboutText on click

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.aboutQuery').click(function() {
  $('.aboutText').hide();
    $('.mySec').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $('.aboutText').fadeIn(5000);
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.mySec {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: calc(95vh);
  width: calc(96vw - 1vh);
  transform: translate(calc((4vw + 1vh) / 2), 2.5vh);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.aboutText {
  padding-left: 5vw;
  padding-right: 5vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  white-space: pre-line;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <ul id="headList">
    <li>
      <a class="aboutQuery" id="link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="link" href="#">CLASSES</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="mySec">
    <div class="info">
      <h1 class="title">Niki Gibbs Modern Pilates</h1>
      <p class="title2">Working From The Inside Out.</p>
      <img id="pilLogo" src="pilatesLog.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aboutSec">
    <div class="aboutInfo">
      <p class="aboutText">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```